# Automatically create folders if does not exists in C#

Tags: c#

So, I am trying to create a file at a specific path but the code I have doesn't allows me to create folders.

This is the code I have:

```
public void LogFiles()
{
    string data = string.Format("LogCarga-{0:yyyy-MM-dd_hh-mm-ss}.txt", DateTime.Now);
    for (int linhas = 0; linhas < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; linhas++)
    {
        if (dataGridView1.Rows[linhas].Cells[8].Value.ToString().Trim() != "M")
        {
            var pathWithEnv = @"%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Cargas - Amostras\_logs\";
            var filePath = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(pathWithEnv);
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
            {
                using (StreamWriter writer = File.AppendText(filePath + data))
                {
                    string carga = dataGridView1.Rows[linhas].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
                    string referencia = dataGridView1.Rows[linhas].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
                    string quantidade = dataGridView1.Rows[linhas].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
                    string dataemissao = dataGridView1.Rows[linhas].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
                    string linha = dataGridView1.Rows[linhas].Cells[4].Value.ToString();
                    string marca = dataGridView1.Rows[linhas].Cells[5].Value.ToString().Trim();
                    string descricaoweb = dataGridView1.Rows[linhas].Cells[6].Value.ToString().Trim();
                    string codprod = dataGridView1.Rows[linhas].Cells[7].Value.ToString().Trim();
                    string tipoemb = dataGridView1.Rows[linhas].Cells[8].Value.ToString().Trim();
                    string nomepc = System.Environment.MachineName;
                    writer.WriteLine(carga + ", " + referencia + ", " + quantidade + ", " + dataemissao + ", " + linha + ", " + marca + ", " + descricaoweb + ", " + codprod + ", "
                            + tipoemb + ", " + nomepc);
                    }  
                }  
            }
        }
    }
```

This `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\` in the universal path and I want to automatically create the `\Cargas - Amostras\_logs\`.

Do you have any idea how to do it?

Comment: Directory.CreateDirectory

Comment: What error are you getting, setting the `OpenOrCreate` flag should be enough.

Comment: check Directory.Exists then create file

Comment: @BalajiMarimuthu you don't even need to do that, you can call `Directory.CreateDirectory` on a existing directly and it will just retrun a refrence to the existing directory instead of throwing a error and trying to create a new one.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain thanks for explanation.

Comment: @BalajiMarimuthu Could you help me with code?

Comment: just a FYI, instead of doing `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local` you could use the variable `%LOCALAPPDATA%`, it points to the same place. (you also could use `Enviorment.GetFolderPath(Enviorment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData)`, that will return the same path as `Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%LOCALAPPDATA%")`

Comment: @SangDang System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(path);

Comment: Thank you for all your help, I were able to solve it with the @BalajiMarimuthu

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The simpelest solution is replace

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
```

with

```
System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(filePath)
```

That will create the directory if it does not exist or do nothing if it does.

Comment: Just a note, if a directory is found, It throws an exception as Exception thrown: 'System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception' in System.dll

Comment: Can you show the code that recreates that, because the documentation is quite clear: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.createdirectory?view=net-5.0 *"Returns: An object that represents the directory at the specified path. This object is returned regardless of whether a directory at the specified path already exists."*

Comment: This is the code System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory("Reports");

Answer (score 0):

You need to create two checks, for your first folder and then second directory.

```
var pathWithEnv = @"%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Cargas - Amostras\";
            if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(pathWithEnv))
            {
                pathWithEnv = System.IO.Path.Combine(pathWithEnv, @"_logs\");
                if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(pathWithEnv))
                {
                //Do what you want to do, both directories are found.    
                }
                else
                {
                    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(pathWithEnv);
                    //Do what you want to do, both directories are available.
                }
            }
            else
            {
                System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(pathWithEnv);

                    pathWithEnv = System.IO.Path.Combine(pathWithEnv, @"_logs\");
                    if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(pathWithEnv))
                    {
                        //Do what you want to do, both directories are available now.
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(pathWithEnv);
                        //Do what you want to do, both directories are created.
                    }
            }
```

Comment: 1) you can call create directory on a directory that exists without issue. 2) create directory will automatically create subfolders you don't need two calls.