# Write temp file and move to .ini file via interface causes Error in C#

Tags: c#, file, task, ini

I have a method which prepares all the necessary data for me and then I work with an interface:

```
myFileCreator.Create(myData.ToString(), PathToWriteMyFile, SomeMoreDataAsAList);
```

My Interface:

```
public interface IMyIniFileCreator
{
    void Create(string dataName, string dataPath, List<SomeModes> modeList);

    void Delete(string dataName, string dataPath);
}
```

It should be noted here that the `Create` and `Delete` methods were previously a `Task`

So

```
public interface IMyIniFileCreator
{
    Task Create(string dataName, string dataPath, List<SomeModes> modeList);

    Task Delete(string dataName, string dataPath);
}
```

The **Create()** looks like the following and should work fine here:

```
public class MyIniFileCreator : ComponentBase,
                                IMyIniFileCreator
{
    public void Create(string dataName, string dataPath, List<SomeModes> modeList)
    {
        var pathToMode = Path.Combine(appDataPath, modeName + ".ini");
        var tempFile = Path.ChangeExtension(pathToMode, "tmp");

        var listOfSection = new List<IniSection>();
        
        // some more code with list of sections etc.
        
        var modeFileInfo = new IniDocument();
        modeFileInfo.AddRange(listOfSection);

        Check.State(tempFile.IsNotNullOrEmpty(), "modes.ini does not exist");

        File.WriteAllText(tempFile, SimpleIniParser.WriteSections(modeFileInfo), Encoding.Default);
        // This is needed when something changes in the file. 
        // Here the old ini must be deleted and the new one written. 
        // Unfortunately we do not have a `ForceMove` available.
        FileSystemHelper.DeleteFileIfExisting(pathToMode);
        FileSystemHelper.MoveDirectory(tempFile, pathToMode);
    }
}
```

The code also runs through and my `modeName.ini` file also exists and has been fully and correctly described.
However the error is thrown that

```
Unable to create directory 'C:\...\data\...\123456789abc.ini'
```

This in turn has the consequence that it goes no further in my main class (line 1). What can be the reason for this, that it still worked with the `Task` in the interface (here a `Task.CompletedTask` was **returned**) and it doesn't work with the `void` anymore and this strange error message appears, although it runs through and the `.ini` file exists.

Comment: please make sure the directory that are storing the file in is existing, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42143052/automatically-create-folders-if-does-not-exists-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling to `MoveDirectory` which is for moving **directories**.

Instead you should call [`File.Move()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.move?view=net-5.0) which is for moving files.

Comment: I'll give it a try, but then why did it work when it was a `Task`?

Because of the return?

Comment: @IanKemp It did work before 100% thats why I'm confused.

Comment: @Ygalbel It works with your solution. Unfortunately, the cause is not yet clear to me. Our FileSystemHelper didn't have any problems with moving the files before. But I just saw that it works only with directories and I am here on file level. Strange that it worked before.